# How does he open the door with the help of a tennis ball?

Tags: plot-explanation, killer-elite

In the film [***Killer Elite***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1448755/), a tennis ball is used to open the door/shed.

[image: An image of a gloved hand pressing a tennis ball against an electronic lock]

How does that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an **urban legend** that electronic locks can be opened by using the air pressure from a tennis ball with a hole in it.

Fortunately, it's not true.

Comment: Should probably be "_fortunately_ it's not true." If that worked, we'd be in trouble. I'd hate for my Lambo to be stolen....

Comment: Good point...updated